# How can I set env vars when using webpack?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nvm

I'm using `nvm`, `webpack` and `yarn` to run a React app locally (not a `create-react-app` app). When I attempt to use environment variables in the terminal session, they are not picked up by the node process.
Steps taken:

In a single terminal session:

- `export FOO=bar`
- `yarn start`
- (in app, `console.log(process.env.FOO)`)
- result = `FOO` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! Added this to the webpack config file:

```
    plugins: [
      new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['FOO']),
    ],
```

make sure you have exported the var in the same terminal you will use to run `yarn`...

```
export FOO=bar
```

then you will be able to access it within your app as `process.env.FOO`

Docs are here:
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/